# Find coordinates of trapezoid if 2 coordines and midpoint of opposite side is known

Tags: geometry

In the below picure A,B and O are known.I need to find C and D.
AB and CD are parallel and O is the midpoint of C and D
Any help is highly appreciated

[image: Trapezoid]

The below is the actual scenario. Radius of 2 circles and center is known. Need to find C and D. Please help

[image: Actual picture]

Comment: $C$ and $D$ can be anywhere along the parallel. If $A$ and $D$ were known instead, *and* it was an isosceles trapezoid, then you would have enough information.

Comment: It can easily be solved if trapezoid is isosceles. i.e AD=BC

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to MSE. Please try to use appropriate tools such as Geogebra or AutoCAD to produce your images. Your question becomes a lot easier to understand with this image:
[image]

We have points $A$ , $B$ and $P$ , which is the midpoint of $CD$. We also have the radii of the two circles. Suppose $CD$ is tangent to the larger circle at $P$. I am adding the assumption that the points $C$ and $D$ are on the extensions of $OB$ and $OA$ , respectively. The problem is to find the points $C$ and $D$.

Please note that without my added assumption, your problem would have an infinite number of solutions.

Please also be consistent in the way you name the elements of your figures. In the upper figure you marked the midpoint of $BC$ as $O$. In the lower figure you marked the midpoint of $BC$ as $P$ and you marked the center of the circle as $O$.

Please be mindful that if you do not care about your own question, then people in here may not be encouraged to help you with it.

You can often expect hints or comments on your own approach in here. You can often not expect people in here to solve your homework problems. I hope you enjoy your experience in MSE. Now, for the start, using the figure I just posted, tell us how you approach this problem, and we will help you further.